# Is the CDF of the Dirac measure the only CDF with positive probability at zero?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, dirac-delta

Consider the set of non-negative real numbers $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ as a measurable space with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}$. Let $\delta_{0}(E) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in E \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ be the Dirac measure at $0$.

Then $(\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, \mathbb{B}, \delta_0)$ is a measure space. Given any measure $\mu$, the CDF $F_\mu$ of $\mu$ is defined as $F_\mu(x) = \mu((-\infty,x])$, so for the Dirac measure we get $F_{\delta_0}(x) = 1$ for all $x \geq 0$, *in particular* for $x = 0$. So the CDF of the Dirac measure violates my usual intuition that a CDF on the non-negative reals starts in $0$ and then increases monotonically, tending towards $1$, because the CDF of the Dirac measure is positive in $0$.

**My question is:** Is the CDF of the Dirac measure the only CDF $F$ such that $F(0) > 0$? In particular, given any number $0 < r < 1$, is there a CDF $F$ such that $F(0) = r$?

Comment: $\mu$ is a finite non-negative Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. For each $x$ look at $f(x) =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \mu((x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon))$. Let $E= \{ x, f(x) > 0\}$. Then $ \nu(A) =\mu(A) - \sum_{x \in E } f(x) \, \delta_x(A) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \mu(A \setminus \bigcup_{x \in E} [x-f(x)\epsilon,x+f(x)\epsilon ]) $ is a finite non-negative continuous Borel measure. Here you are looking at measures supported on $[0,\infty)$ : $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \mu((-\infty,-\epsilon)) =0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) is a **non-decreasing** and **right-continuous** function $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with: $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0\text{ and }\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=1$$

So evidently for every $r\in[0,1]$ there are lots of CDF's with $F(0)=r$.

This remains true under the extra condition that $F(x)=0$ for negative $x$, except for $r=1$.

Exactly one CDF with $F(x)=0$ for negative $x$ also satisfies $F(0)=1$

---

Every CDF determines a probability measure and the CDF with $F(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $F(0)=1$ determines the Dirac measure at $0$.